# Alias [keystone.js] and [keystonejs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The [keystone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystone.js) and [keystonejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystonejs) should be aliased as they both refer to the same library.

As the [official name is KeystoneJS](http://keystonejs.com/), I propose keeping that as the primary and aliasing [keystone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystone.js) to it.

Comment: It's easier to just retag those questions. Takes 0 moderator time.

Comment: There's a reverse proposal, keeping [keystone.js] as the master. Are you sure that you want the opposite?

Comment: I'm in favor of OP's proposal to make `keystonejs` the master since, indeed, that is how they brand it all over their site (aside from casing).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these questions have been tagged just with [keystone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystone.js) and [keystonejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystonejs) alone. There's also a third one floating around that does **not** appear to be the same thing: [keystone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystone).

I've started removing the extra tags on questions tagged with both of them, at least, per the OP's recommendation according to the official name. ([keystone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystone.js) -> [keystonejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystonejs)).

---

That's done. I'll leave the rest to the moderators when they merge the tags. Or to the users, if enough vote for synonymization.

Answer (score 0):

This is now done.

Currently keystonejs is the master, and keystone.js maps to it; as, like you said, it seems to be the "official" name.

We can always reverse the synonym later if needed.